# What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to clone some fields and use some functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a form where a select menu is cloned and appended. In each clone there is a jQuery drop-down selector that I have created a function called **unitClone** that you can see towards the end of the JavaScript code.

```
unitClone = function(input) {
    var id = $('#' + input + ' .unit_select').attr('id');
    var id = ('#' + id);
    //alert(id);
    dd = new Select($(id));
    var selected = $(id).closest('td').find('.ingredient_unit').val();
    if (selected != null) {
        var selected = $(id).find(".dropdown li a[data-id=" + selected + "]").html();
        $(id).find('span').text(selected);
    }
}
```

For some reason the code is not working properly, the first item does not allow me to click and select and the third item allows me to select but the same value is used for all the drop-downs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tlaverdure/nKrvh/

Comment: Haven't looked at your fiddle, but why are you declaring `var id` twice and why are you using `dd` as a global? And what is `new Select`

Comment: Do you have an suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. `.live` was not working out.

```
obj.dd.toggle(function() {
        selectArea = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+ selectArea).addClass('active');
        return false;
        },
        function(){
            selectArea = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#'+ selectArea).removeClass('active');
             return true;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tlaverdure/nKrvh/3/

Answer (score 2):

I change the **on** method in your js code to **live** and everythings work fine

```
Select.prototype = {
    initEvents: function() {
        var obj = this;
        obj.dd.live('click', function(event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
        obj.opts.live('click', function() {
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            var num = $(this).closest('td').find('.num');
            var numVal = $(this).closest('td').find('.num').val();
            if (numVal > 1) {
                obj.val = obj.val + 's'
            }
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
            obj.opt_id = opt.find('a').data('id');
            $('.recipe_difficulty').val(obj.opt_id);
        });
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex: function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MXPjL/1/) is the edited code.

Good luck

Comment: @Barmar , Yes , I know. I just answered the question.

Comment: Hey @AliForoughi can you try adding a few lines and then deleting and then trying to add some more again? It stops working if you attempt to delete some clones and start again.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with `$(this).toggleClass('active');` all the elements neccesary are present but when you delete a clone and then try to replace it toggleClass does not work. Any ideas?